# is twitter_anywhere_identity useable as an access token?

Tags: python, twitter, oauth, identity, twitter-anywhere

After messing with oauth and discovering the final leg of twitter oauth was not reliably sending back the oauth_verifier (though it seemed to authenticate anyway!), i got a bit disgruntled.

then i discovered @anywhere, the javascript twitter lib, and thought i'd give it a go.

@anywhere out of the box seems designed to allow one to do stuff like setup a tweetbox on your page. this is quite lovely but i also want my app to be able to interact with twitter server-side, i.e. from a Django script.

the auth cycle from @anywhere returns a cookie called twitter_anywhere_identity.

its format is defined as something like "userid:signature" where the signature is verifiable via hashing against the application consumer secret to prove that the cookie really came from twitter.

BUT can anyone tell me whether/how the twitter_anywhere_identity cookie (*contains information that?)* can be used as an access token?  (if not, i'm going back to normal oauth...i guess.)

speaking of which, can anyone tell me which python library is **really** the best for twitter?  there seem to be about 8 of them out there.

thanks!

jingles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter's @themattharris pre announced @Anywhere oauth_bridge_code support. You will be able to get an oauth 1.0a token by this API.

See http://blog.abrah.am/2010/09/using-twitter-anywhere-bridge-codes.html for details.

Comment: thanks. i may never actually use this now that i've gone the backend route but it's nice to know about.

Answer (score 1):

**Not yet, but in the works,** if I correctly interpret an August 9th comment from Taylor Singletary:

> We'll have a solution for this
>   announced soon that will allow you to
>   move more seamlessly between the
>   (non-OAuth 1.0a) access tokens that
>   make up @Anywhere requests and
>   server-side REST requests using OAuth
>   1.0a access tokens.

http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/2ec8f0ce984fd6e5/8e4db35fa82b22ca?lnk=gst&q=%40anywhere#8e4db35fa82b22ca

meantime, i got my OAuth1.0a solution working and i'm cool with that.  ;)

JB